# PFQuery.getObjectWithId(objectId: String) --- 'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String' error --- Parse sdk 1.7.1 and Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I just updated Xcode to 6.3 and my parse sdk to 1.7.1. I knew from the apple docs that I was going to spend some time fixing some of my swift code on my iOS app. Xcode is happy with all my fixes except for one func that gets a parse class by id. I've dredged parse, apple, stackoverflow, and google for a fix, but I've been banging my head against this last fix for hours and desperately need some help from one of you super smart guys. I apologize in advance if this turns out to be a stupid question. I've been programming for a really long time, but I'm a noob to iOS.

Below is a simple example of what I'm trying to do, which worked before I updated Xcode and parse sdk. Now Xcode gives me errors for each of the lines where I am trying to get the variables out from the PFObject. Errors for each line is like this: "'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String'" and "Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'String". Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
func getFakeObject(objectId: String) -> FakeObject {

    var fakeObject: FakeObject = FakeObject()
    var query = PFQuery(className:"FakeObject")
    var loadedFakeObject = query.getObjectWithId(objectId)
    if loadedFakeObject != nil {

            fakeObject.objectId = objectId
            fakeObject.isActive = loadedFakeObject["isActive"] as! Bool
            fakeObject.desc = loadedFakeObject["desc"] as! String
            fakeObject.purchasePrice = loadedFakeObject["purchasePrice"] as! Double
            fakeObject.purchaseDate = loadedFakeObject["purchaseDate"] as! NSDate
            fakeObject.labels = loadedFakeObject["labels"] as [String]

    }
    return fakeObject
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 1.2 is a lot stricter about syntax and tries to prevent you from unknowingly doing dangerous things.

Where you write:

```
var loadedFakeObject = query.getObjectWithId(objectId)
if loadedFakeObject != nil {
```

Try instead:

```
if let loadedFakeObject = query.getObjectWithId(objectId) {
```

In the first case, you are getting an optional (there might be no such object), and then checking it its `nil`, but then still using the optional.  Because it’s optional, you need to write `loadedFakeObject!["isActive"] as! Bool`.  But there’s really no need because instead you can use `if let` to both check *and* unwrap the optional, meaning within the `if` statement, it won’t be optional any more.

You might also want to consider switching to `as?` instead of `as!` in various places, but this is probably less the cause of your problem, more of a runtime safety thing.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are my hero! That did the trick and now all my errors are fixed. I'd give you 100 votes if I could.